# PySpark Schema structure to read nested data

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am getting following error.

> ValueError: field col4: Length of object (1) does not match with length of fields (2)

The data is in this format.

```
[
  ["N","S","3",null,null],
  ["N","P","4",[{"key1":"val1","key2":"val2"}],null],
  ["N","I","5",null,[{"key1":"val1","key2":"val2"}]],
  ["N","S","3",null,null]
]
```

The Schema I have defined is following:

```
schema = StructType(
  StructField("col1", StringType(), True),
  StructField("col2", StringType(), True),
  StructField("col3", StringType(), True),
  StructField("col4",
    StructType(
      StructField("key1", StringType(), True),
      StructField("key2", StringType(), True)
    )
  ),
  StructField("col5",
    StructType(
      StructField("key1", StringType(), True),
      StructField("key2", StringType(), True)
    )
  )
)
```

Please help me in identifying how I can read the data of this format.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to replace `null` with `None`, as `null` is not a keyword in either `python` or `pyspark` (unless you are using `spark-sql`).

Now regarding your schema - you need to define it as `ArrayType` wherever `complex` or `list` column structure is there. Inside that, you again need to specify `StructType` because within your list there is a `dictionary` with `key` and `value` pairs.
See below structure to visualize it better -

```
data = [["N","S","3",None,None], ["N","P","4",[{"key1":"val1","key2":"val2"}],None], ["N","I","5",None,[{"key1":"val1","key2":"val2"}]], ["N","S","3",None, None] ]
```

You need to convert this to a `RDD` as below -

```
data_rdd = sc.parallelize(data)
```

Once you're `RDD` is created then you need to create your dataframe using the `schema` I explained above -

```
from pyspark.sql.types import *

schema = schema = StructType(
  [StructField("col1", StringType(), True),
  StructField("col2", StringType(), True),
  StructField("col3", StringType(), True),
  StructField("col4",
    ArrayType(
      StructType([StructField("key1", StringType(), True),
      StructField("key2", StringType(), True)])
    )
  ),
  StructField("col5",
    ArrayType(
      StructType([StructField("key1", StringType(), True),
      StructField("key2", StringType(), True)])
    )
  )
  ]
)

df = spark.createDataFrame(data=data_rdd, schema=schema)
```

**Output**

```
df.show()

+----+----+----+--------------+--------------+
|col1|col2|col3|          col4|          col5|
+----+----+----+--------------+--------------+
|   N|   S|   3|          null|          null|
|   N|   P|   4|[{val1, val2}]|          null|
|   N|   I|   5|          null|[{val1, val2}]|
|   N|   S|   3|          null|          null|
+----+----+----+--------------+--------------+
```

Additionally, if you need the `key` and `value` as separate `columns` for both `col4` and `col5`, in that case you need to create the schema as below -

```
schema = StructType(
  [StructField("col1", StringType(), True),
  StructField("col2", StringType(), True),
  StructField("col3", StringType(), True),
  StructField("col4", 
              ArrayType(
                MapType(StringType(), StringType())
              )
             ),
  StructField("col5", 
              ArrayType(
                MapType(StringType(), StringType())
              )
             )
  ]
)

from pyspark.sql.functions import *

df = spark.createDataFrame(data=sc.parallelize(data), schema=schema)

df.show(truncate=False)

#Input dataframe output - 
+----+----+----+------------------------------+------------------------------+
|col1|col2|col3|col4                          |col5                          |
+----+----+----+------------------------------+------------------------------+
|N   |S   |3   |null                          |null                          |
|N   |P   |4   |[{key1 -> val1, key2 -> val2}]|null                          |
|N   |I   |5   |null                          |[{key1 -> val1, key2 -> val2}]|
|N   |S   |3   |null                          |null                          |
+----+----+----+------------------------------+------------------------------+
```

Finally, explode these columns `col4` and `col5` as below -

```
(df.withColumn('explode_col4',  explode_outer( col('col4')))
   .withColumn('explode_col5', explode_outer( col('col5')))
   .select("col1", "col2", "col3", (explode_outer( col('explode_col4') ).alias('col4_key', 'col4_value')) , "explode_col5")
   .select("col1", "col2", "col3", "col4_key", "col4_value", (explode_outer( col('explode_col5') ).alias('col5_key', 'col5_value')))
).show(truncate=False)
```

**Output**

```
+----+----+----+--------+----------+--------+----------+
|col1|col2|col3|col4_key|col4_value|col5_key|col5_value|
+----+----+----+--------+----------+--------+----------+
|N   |S   |3   |null    |null      |null    |null      |
|N   |P   |4   |key1    |val1      |null    |null      |
|N   |P   |4   |key2    |val2      |null    |null      |
|N   |I   |5   |null    |null      |key1    |val1      |
|N   |I   |5   |null    |null      |key2    |val2      |
|N   |S   |3   |null    |null      |null    |null      |
+----+----+----+--------+----------+--------+----------+
```